# How to enable multilingual support in wordpress.com blog

Tags: wordpress

I want to enable multilingual support in my wordpress.com blog? Is there any plugin or option for that? I just want user to be able to have automatic translation of my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think wordpress.com doesn't have such an option for now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Transposh WordPress Translation Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/). It offers you the possibility to translate automaticly your blog into other languages, but with the option to translate some parts of the blog by yourself if you need to.

I used it on a project, and I'm pretty sure it would fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois. Unfortunately I am looking for the solution on wordpress.com hosted blogs not self hosted blogs. Wordpress.com doesn't allow custom plugins